# BlackRock IVV ownership

Tags: stocks, etf

As I was looking through BlackRock recent released 13F, how does BlackRock have ownership in IVV which is an S&P 500 ETF they managed? In other words, how could a company have ownership in shares they issued?

Comment: I'm not certain what problem you see with this - they don't choose the investments (it's an index tracker) so what problem would there be with them owning shares? Note that it's different than a company "owning" shares of _itself_.

Comment: Do they just issue new shares when they want to purchase it or they would purchase it from the market?

Comment: @RonJohn I don't think that's the question - I think the question is why/how does Blackrock own shares in the IVV fund that they manage, not their own stock.